# Should I use the modified Z-score formulation to normalize my data

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, normalization

Usually, min max normalization or z-score normalization is used for machine learning.  However, they are not robust to outliers.  And I did not remove "outliers" in my data because the data is very high dimensional and in the multivariate case, it may not be outliers.

So I was wondering if I can use the modified Z-score method to normalize my data as follows:

[image]

[image]

If I can't why, why not?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a programming question, better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).